# Resizing 2D vector in C++ and fill with 0

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I've got integers n and m and two vectors:

```
vector< vector<int> > inputGrid;
vector< vector<int> > outputGrid;
```

How do I resize the 2D vectors to (n, m) and put a 0 in place?

Thanks

Comment: If you know `(n, m)` beforehand, you can construct the vectors to the desired sizes.  E.g. for inputGrid:  `vector< vector<int> > inputGrid(n, vector<int>(m,0));`

Comment: Are you sure you want the grid to reside in "jagged" memory? (Each sub vector points to a different buffer).

Comment: The m and n are in a loop, so I don't know them before hand. The answer down there works, is there another way besides using a 2D array? I'm not really sure what you mean by the jagged memory/buffer

Answer (score 2):

Where n is the column, and m is the row.

```
inputGrid.resize(n, std::vector<int>(m, 0));
outputGrid.resize(n, std::vector<int>(m, 0));
```

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), there's some more information on the 2D vectors and [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/).

I hope this helps!